# ngrok does not work with react-router when deep links are explicitly defined

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Context: I'm opening up my React dev environment to external hits using a paid version of the tool `ngrok` -- I am running `WebPack 4.0` with a `devServer`.

I go to my app's main page:

```
https://my-example-domain.ngrok.io
```

Loads fine.

I click one of the links on my app's main page, The router works well and I see the content for:

```
https://my-example-domain.ngrok.io/my-sub-page
```

However, if I refresh at this point, ngrok gives out a `404`:

```
Cannot GET /my-sub-page
```

The reason I suspect is that in a `SPA`, the internal app's URLs are processed by the front end in `React-Router` and externally, there is no resource called `/my-sub-page`

Is there a way to force this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This resolved it -- in `webpack.config.js`

```
 devServer: {
    ...
    ...
    historyApiFallback: true,    // <- inserting this resolved the issue. 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the local server doesn't know about your spa routes(react-router). To fix this, you have to create a simple server that will serve your **static build** and have a fallback route that will enable spa-routing.

Example in express.js:

```html
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
// ... other imports

const app = express();

app.use(express.static('build'));

/*
... some route handlers

*/

// * Unknown endpoint
app.use("/*",  (_req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../build/index.html"), (err) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err);
    }
  });
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000 , ()=>{
  console.log('server running')
})
```